# Lightbox 'next' feature still showing elements (li) that have been hidden with display:none;

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an unordered list (ul) with list tags (li) and I have some jQuery filtering them into two groups. Once you click the item, in this case an image, a light-box pops up. Everything up to here works (the filtering of the (li) elements into their respective groups and the light-box).

Here's the problem, once I have the images filtered, the light box has a 'next' feature that will display the next (li) picture even if it's been filtered out. The filter is setting the thumbnail of the (li) that has been filtered out to display:none; in the css.

**Is there a way I can tell the light-box through jQuery to ignore elements that have been hidden with display:none;?** It seems simple enough but but my knowledge outside of html and css is quite limited for now.

PS: I've been looking around a few places and I've found code that would work but it removes the (li) from the page and you'd have to refresh the page for it to show up again. This is not what I want since I have a 'show all' button for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .filter to get only visible elements e.g

```
$('.class').filter(':visible');
```